# Adding line breaks to concatenating functions?

Tags: r, string, function, concatenation

what is the command I have to use to adding linebreaks while concatenating functions?

Here is the script:

```
canada <- c(50, 50, 50)
korea <- c(70, 70, 70)
brazil <- c(100, 100, 100)
fruit <- rbind(canada, korea, brazil)
colnames(fruit) <- c("apple", "orange", "banana")

one <- function(x){
  x <- tolower(x) # assuming all row names are in lower case
  myrow <- fruit[x,]

  count <- sapply(seq_along(myrow), 
                       function(x, n, i) 
                       {paste0(x[i], "")},
                       x=myrow[1], n=names(myrow))
  count[length(count)] <- paste0(count[length(count)])
  count <- paste(count[1])

  cat(tools::toTitleCase(x), "has", count, "thousand farms") # General statement
}
```

Here is what I've tried:

```
cat(one("canada"), '\n\n', one("canada"))
Canada has 50 thousand farmsCanada has 50 thousand farms
```

I want it to look like this:

```
Canada has 50 thousand farms

Canada has 50 thousand farms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that within your funciton you use cat where you should use paste (check ?paste and ?cat to understand the differences). with this funciton it should work fine:

```
one <- function(x){
    x <- tolower(x) # assuming all row names are in lower case
    myrow <- fruit[x,]

    count <- sapply(seq_along(myrow), 
                                    function(x, n, i) 
                                    {paste0(x[i], "")},
                                    x=myrow[1], n=names(myrow))
    count[length(count)] <- paste0(count[length(count)])
    count <- paste(count[1])

    ret <- paste(tools::toTitleCase(x), "has", count, "thousand farms") # General statement
}
```

in order to remove trailing blanks from the second line, you have to add sep="" to the last statement:

```
cat(one("canada"), ' \n\n ', one("canada"), sep="")
```